# Extract arrays of values from same column values in pandas

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, dataframe, subset

I'm improving knowledge with pandas but I have a problem right now. 
I have this DataFrame structure. 
Mainly I would to extract arrays of PrpSummed based on same Lat/Lon points.

```
         Year  Month   PrpSummed   Lat    Lon       Country
0        1980      1   46.877298 -34.5  -9.75  Saint Helena
7477     1980      2  204.177988 -34.5  -9.75  Saint Helena
14954    1980      3  117.243914 -34.5  -9.75  Saint Helena
22431    1980      4  374.656000 -34.5  -9.75  Saint Helena
29908    1980      5  177.617108 -34.5  -9.75  Saint Helena
37385    1980      6  151.473215 -34.5  -9.75  Saint Helena
44862    1980      7  388.515026 -34.5  -9.75  Saint Helena
52339    1980      8  221.093829 -34.5  -9.75  Saint Helena
59816    1980      9  264.000056 -34.5  -9.75  Saint Helena
67293    1980     10  132.107333 -34.5  -9.75  Saint Helena
74770    1980     11   62.275033 -34.5  -9.75  Saint Helena
82247    1980     12  166.834219 -34.5  -9.75  Saint Helena
89724    1981      1  167.100545 -34.5  -9.75  Saint Helena
97201    1981      2   57.451788 -34.5  -9.75  Saint Helena
104678   1981      3  142.887079 -34.5  -9.75  Saint Helena
112155   1981      4  118.741756 -34.5  -9.75  Saint Helena
...       ...    ...         ...   ...    ...           ...
3429697  2016      9  177.563373  37.5  51.00          Iran
3437747  2016     10  243.134902  37.5  51.00          Iran
3445797  2016     11  247.394538  37.5  51.00          Iran
3453847  2016     12  203.338263  37.5  51.00          Iran
3461897  2017      1  113.151845  37.5  51.00          Iran
3469947  2017      2  183.991026  37.5  51.00          Iran
3477997  2017      3  118.528012  37.5  51.00          Iran
3486047  2017      4  132.959934  37.5  51.00          Iran
3494097  2017      5   19.248508  37.5  51.00          Iran
3502147  2017      6    6.919063  37.5  51.00          Iran
3510197  2017      7   68.626854  37.5  51.00          Iran
3518247  2017      8    9.220729  37.5  51.00          Iran
3526297  2017      9  118.219854  37.5  51.00          Iran
3534347  2017     10  224.305352  37.5  51.00          Iran
3542397  2017     11  475.362162  37.5  51.00          Iran
3550447  2017     12  135.747279  37.5  51.00          Iran
```

Furthermore, after this, I have to calculate some external statistic operation with every array and then insert in DataFrame a new column with new monthly stats. Someone can help me?

Expected output

```
arrayPrp = [
[46.877298,204.177988,117.243914,177.617108 ...],...,[177.563373,243.134902,247.394538,203.338263...]
 ]
```

And finally

```
       Year  Month   PrpSummed   Lat    Lon       Country   SPI
0        1980      1   46.877298 -34.5  -9.75  Saint Helena 0.5
7477     1980      2  204.177988 -34.5  -9.75  Saint Helena 0.4
14954    1980      3  117.243914 -34.5  -9.75  Saint Helena 0.3
22431    1980      4  374.656000 -34.5  -9.75  Saint Helena 0.2
29908    1980      5  177.617108 -34.5  -9.75  Saint Helena 0.8
...
```

Comment: What *specifically* are you trying to do, currently this question is extremely vague.

Comment: I would like to have a list of arrays of PrpSummed based on Latitude and Longitude points.

Comment: `df.groupby(['Lat', 'Lon']).size()` would give you a df of PrpSummed based on Lat and Lon.

Comment: What determines the groups? Identical points? Distance apart using haversine?

Comment: Then I will apply a function to each array that return me a specific number (like quantile) for every value of the array, and I want to insert this values in a new column of the data frame.

Comment: Answering DJK, identical points.

Comment: @Darkwilmore can you post the expected output?

Comment: Edited the initial post.

Comment: @Darkwilmore How do you compute `SPI`?

Comment: With external library that get in input an array and return an array with same dimension. It is not important at the moment I think.